# PHPMailer does not overwrite $mail->Body in Loop

Tags: php, phpmailer, sendmail

I am sending emails to clients using a loop.

The Body (email message) is merged in the loop with the client data from a MySQL database, such as name etc. to personalise the email.

The problem is that every email is sent with the same Body. PHPMailer does not overwrite the Body with the new merged message in each iteration of the loop.

Example:

```
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) { f
    $message = "Hello " . $recipient->fname . ' ' . $recipient->lname . "...."
    // remainder of code below....
}
```

Will send all emails to "Hello Jane Doe.... "

Here is the code I am using

```
$maillist = new maillist; // this is a custom class
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSendmail();
$mail->isHTML(true);   
$mail->ClearAllRecipients();

// message body and subject
$subject = "This is the subject";
$message_body = "Hello {fname} {lname}.... ";

// set the sender info
$sender_email = "support@mydomain.com"; 
$sender_name = "My Website Name";

// get the recipients for the email from a function in the maiilist class
$recipients = $maillist->selectRecipients();

foreach ($recipients as $recipient) { 

    $id = $recipient->id;
    $fname = $recipient->fname; // Recipient first name
    $lname = $recipient->lname; // recipient last name
    $email = $recipient->email; // recipient email address

    // merge the reipient data into message
    $before = array("{fname}", "{lname}");
    $after = array($fname, $lname);
    $message = str_replace($before, $after, $message_body);

    // send the email using PHPMailer
    $mail->setFrom($sender_email, $sender_name);
    $mail->addAddress($email);      
    $mail->addReplyTo($sender_email);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $message;
    $email_message = $mail->send(); 
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

    // log sent message in database
    if ($email_message) {
        $maillist->logMessage($id, $email, $subject, $message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you sure it's not supposed to be `fname`? That's what you're using elsewhere.

Comment: the question's unclear. You seem to be using some form of mailing list and/or a class. Are you not present here or are you simply ignoring comments and waiting for an instant solution? You have `$message_body = "Hello {fname} {lname}.... ";` but nowhere is that "Dear..." of yours in that big body of code. I'll just pass on this one, good luck.

Comment: The "Dear..." was an example of the problem. I added the actual code for clarity. The maillist class in this case has a method that selects recipients, as per the comment in the code. fname is simply a variable populated from the database in the loop. Ill edit to spell things out a bit more

Comment: I have editied the code with some extra comments for clarity

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with PHPMailer. You're just having trouble with a search and replace in a string. Once you've fixed that, PHPMailer will use whatever you give it. Also, you don't need to call `ClearAllRecipients` on a new instance, and why are you using `isSendmail()`? That's a very unusual thing to need; use `isSMTP()` with `Host = 'localhost'` in preference to that; it's safer and faster.

Comment: Actually, if I echo out the email body in the loop, it is populating each email correctly, however it seems that PHPMaiiler is sending the message from the first iteration of the loop to every recipient. I only used clear recipients on a new instance to be safe I guess as I did see this done in an example somewhere. I know it isn't necessary, and will remove that.